# Borrar elemento de una pila

Tags: c#, pilas

Tengo una pila de tipo entero en la consola de `c#` y quiero borrar un elemento dentro de la misma, el elemento lo debe de escribir el usuario, por ejemplo:
Si en la pila tengo los datos: 12, 34, 54, 6, 44 en pantalla saldrá un mensaje: "Ingrese el dato que desea borrar", si el usuario ingresa 44 se debe de mostrar en pantalla la pila ya sin el dato.
Lo estoy haciendo con el método Pop pero tengo un problema, pop solo me elimina el primer dato, yo quiero que elimine un dato especifico

### ESTE MÉTODO SOLO BORRA EL PRIMER DATO:

```
 public void usePop()
 {
     showStackElements();
     Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el valor que desea eliminar");
     int valor = (int)stack.Pop();
     Console.WriteLine("Elemento " + valor + " eliminado");
 }
```

---

He modificado el código tratando de guardar una variable (valor) he ingresando esa variable en el método `stack.Pop(valor)` pero me da error.

### CÓDIGO CON ERROR:

```
 public void usePop()
 {
     showStackElements();
     Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el valor que desea eliminar");
     int valor = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
     stack.Pop(valor);

     Console.WriteLine("Elemento " + valor + " eliminado");
 }
```

---

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Por definición, en una pila sólo puedes eliminar el elemento que está en la cima. Las pilas son estructuras que siguen el principio LIFO (Last In First Out, último entrar primero en salir), en otras palabras, con un objeto de la clase Stack no vas a lograr tu objetivo. Una estructura que te permite eliminar cualquier elemento que contenga es la lista (clase List), utilizando el método Remove, por ejemplo:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el valor que desea eliminar");
    int valor = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    list.Remove(valor);
    Console.WriteLine("Elemento " + valor + " eliminado");
```

Answer (score 1):

La solución típica de este problema yo la realizaría con una pila secundaria, a donde voy *volteando* los datos de la primera pila hasta encontrar el valor a eliminar, y luego, regresando todos los elementos a la pila original (valiendome del hecho de que la pila me devolverá primero el último elemento ingresado, por lo que quedarán en el mismo orden en el que estaban originalmente).

Dado que es código muy simple, y la idea es que aprendas, te daré la solución en pseudo-código, que sería algo como:

```
Pedir valor a eliminar;
repetir
  Sacar un elemento de la pila original;
  Si no es igual al elemento a Eliminar
    Poner el elemento en la pila secundaria
hasta que la pila original esté vacía o el elemento sea igual al elemento a eliminar
repetir
  Sacar un elemento de la pila secundaria
  Poner el elemento en la pila original
hasta que la pila secundaria esté vacía.
```

UN saludo.